# маска для input

Tags: javascript

есть скрипт для поля email, и при наведении на него курсора появляется маска такого вида `_@_._`, как эту маску по умолчанию поставить, и не нужно было наводить курсор?

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#contactsForm").inputmask("email")
  });



 <input name="contactsForm" type="text" id="contactsForm">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно установить значения атрибута `placeholder`

```html
<input name="contactsForm" type="text" id="contactsForm" placeholder="email">
```

**UPDATE**

попробуйте так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#contactsForm").inputmask("email",{placeholder:" ", clearMaskOnLostFocus: false }); 
});
```

Comment: маска _@_._ появляется при наведении на поле курсора, как сделать что бы она постоянно такова была?

Comment: @аноним обновил ответ